# CSS Help selecting the last element with a class certain class

Tags: javascript, css, html

Just need help in writing a CSS selector.
I want to select the last element of the below that has a class of RED

```
#tData td:nth-child(8)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to attache the RED class to the selector.

Comment: Use last-child selector, I think it can help you. https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:last-child

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice, not a duplicate. The other question is about selecting  the last child having a particular class, which is not possible using CSS selectors. In CSS you can't select the first, last or n-th of a particular collection (selector). It can be done using Javascript, though.

Comment: Not a duplicate question.   The other question does not take into consideration that other columns can have a Red Class. Hence i was specific on the last cell in 8th column that is red.   If that question was answered  in  that posting, i might be blind to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#tData td.red:nth-child(8) {}
```

will select any 8th cell in its row, if the cell has "red" class, inside `#tData`.

If you want to select the last element in the `<tr>`, if that last element has the class of "red", use:

```css
#tData td.red:last-child {}
```

Comment: Will this work if i have other cells that have red, which are not the 8th?  I only want the 8 column.

Comment: It will only select elements that satisfy all conditions at same time: are 8th child of their parent, have "red" class and are inside an element with id "tData" (this is about the first selector).

Comment: That is why i added the comment, because it does not meet all . it fails on selecting the last one and the one that does, will fail because there ar other red class in other columns

Comment: @Dewinky, your question was not clear enough. From your comment under it, I now understand you want to select the last cell in the eighth column to have a class of `red`. If that's what you want, it's not possible with CSS. You can't select the last, first of n-th element a particular selector and your question is, in fact, a duplicate.